# Rails - HighVoltage gem - link with anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I have a problem with HighVoltage when I try to link to anchor on the static page. In the URL I am receiving '%23' instead of '#'.

Example

```
  <%= link_to 'xxx', page_path('xxx#yyy') %>
```

gives in the URL:

```
  http://localhost:3000/pages/xxx%23yyy
```

Can somebody give ma a hint how it can be solved, as I did not find any related information in the gem documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to and the param anchor, for example:

link_to "About", page_path('index', anchor: "about")