# Rails - HighVoltage - link anchor with title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I am using the High_Voltage gem to integrate static pages in my rails gem. I figured out how to link to anchors within a page (thanks to [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025694/rails-highvoltage-gem-link-with-anchor). Now I also want to add a pop-up title to the links. I just randomly tried

```
link_to "About", page_path('indexpage', anchor: "aboutsection", title: "MyAboutTitle")
```

But this renders to

```html
<a href="/pages/indexpage?title=MyAboutTitle#aboutsection">About</a>
```

and, logically, does not produce the desired result. 
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rail API for [link_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) to add html options, the `title` argument should be placed third in the method call, like this:

```
link_to "About", page_path('indexpage', anchor: "aboutsection"), title: "MyAboutTitle"
```

and it will output:

```html
<a href="/pages/indexpage#aboutsection" title="MyAboutTitle">About</a>
```